# Process geting killed while loading data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm working on my master thesis which is about skin cancer detection using. I was trying a method using a SVM after extracting features, but that's not really important right now. The problem is, when I try to load the data, the process gets killed. The full data (images) has a few thousand samples (2000 in training, 2000 in superpixels for training, plus a couple thousand more in validation data), but anything more than around 1500 and it gets killed while loading the data. I'm not sure if I'm approaching the data loading in the most efficient way, most likely I'm not. I use the getData function to load the data. Nevermind the comments. The error message in the terminal simply says Killed, it has no exit code.

```
def getData(desiredData, superpixel, limit):
    rootDir = '.'
    Data = []
    i = 0
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=True):
        if dirName == './Data' + '/' + desiredData:
            fileList.sort()
            for fname in fileList:
                if superpixel:
                    if "superpixels" in fname:
                        temp = misc.imread(dirName + '/' + fname)
                        Data.append(temp[:,:,0])
                        #print(temp.shape)
                        if limit != 0:
                            i += 1
                            if i == limit:
                                print('Done loading ' + desiredData)
                                return Data
                else:
                    if "superpixels" not in fname:
                        temp = misc.imread(dirName + '/' + fname)
                        Data.append(temp)
                        #print(temp.shape)
                        if limit != 0:
                            i += 1
                            if i == limit:
                                print('Done loading ' + desiredData)
                                return Data
    print('Done loading ' + desiredData)
    return Data
```

If you can, take a look at it and see if what's causing this is in the code I use, that'd be great. Any optimization problems you came across that aren't really related to this, feel free to comment on too.

Comment: Please include code in your question, not as an external link (which is full of ads).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be running out of memory - this is the most common reason for a process to be killed. You might want to `tail` the file `/var/log/kern.log` when the process gets killed for more information.

Comment: Yeah that's what I saw in most of other related questions. But isn't there a way to get around this problem? The only option is to get a more powerful computer?

Comment: Would it be possible to reformat your code so that you don't have to load the entire dataset into memory? Could you, for example, load each image one at a time and process them, rather than loading all images in one go?

Comment: Well, I could, but how do I control what stays in memory? I'm a newbie to python.

Comment: When opening files in Python you can use one of two methods to ensure that they only stay open for as long as you need them. You can either use `open()` and `close()`, or wrap your code in `with open()`. You can read more at https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python. If you provide some code samples we might be able to provide more specific help.

Comment: I gave the link to the code file, can't you see it?